# Equivalent gprnd(MATLAB) method in Python

Tags: python, matlab, scipy

I'm looking for an equivalent method of **gprnd** (Generalized Pareto random number) in python. In Matlab, we have `r = gprnd(k,sigma,theta)`. I checked out [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.pareto.html) but I didn't understand how to implement it. The documentation is very less and I don't have a lot of knowledge in this.

I have `k, sigma and theta` values.

Thanks.

Comment: Would [`numpy.random.pareto`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.pareto.html) work?

Comment: @stybl: May you please write the method call which will take the three parameters (k, sigma, theta) I mentioned in my question?

Comment: What you want is more like `scipy.stats.genpareto.rvs(k, sigma, theta)`.

Comment: @kazemakase: According to [the matlab docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/gprnd.html), `sigma` is the scale and `theta` is the location, so it would be `scipy.stats.genpareto.rvs(k, theta, sigma)` (or, more expliclty, `scipy.stats.genpareto.rvs(k, loc=theta, scale=sigma)`).

Comment: Oops. Thank you @warren, that's right of course.

Answer (score 3):

Comparing the documentation for [Matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/gprnd.html) and [SciPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.genpareto.html#scipy.stats.genpareto), it looks like `scipy.stats.genpareto.rvs()` has the signature `rvs(c, loc=0, scale=1, size=1, random_state=None)`.  `c` corresponds to the shape parameter `k`, `loc` corresponds to the threshold parameter `theta`, and `scale` corresponds to the scale parameter `sigma`.

Comment: You confused CDF, PDF and random number generation. OP asked for matlab's **gprnd** so the `.rvs` method will be more useful than `.pdf`.

Comment: Thanks. I can't upvote this answer as I don't have 15 reputation. Maybe someone can upvote my question and I can upvote this answer. :)